# Select all first options

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

from the following markup, I want to get options a1, (all), and a. I was using `$("option:first-child")` until I added `optgroup` to some of the selects. Now that code selects a1, b1, (all), 1, 3, and a.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="a">
    <option>a1</option>
    <option>a2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="b">
    <option>b1</option>
    <option>b2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<select>
  <option>(all)</option>
  <optgroup label="a">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="b">
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<select>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("select > option:first-child, optgroup:first-child > option:first-child")
```

The first part will get the first `option` for `select`s with no `optgroup`.  The 2nd gets the first `option` of the first `optgroup`.

Though I'm slightly confused by your original example because I don't believe you would get `a` in that case because the first option is the `(all)` option and not `a`.

Comment: sorry, my example was incomplete

Comment: I believe this should still work.   http://jsfiddle.net/zh4X8/1/  Made them multi for the example so that you can clearly see which ones were made red.

Answer (score 2):

This will select a1, (all) and a:

```
$('select').find('option:first').each( function(ix) { alert(this.text); } );
```

Actually this will always select first option in each select.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it for you:

```
$('optgroup.a > option:first-child, select > option:first-child')
```

You're selecting the first child of any `select` that is an `option`, and in addition, specifically selecting the first child of `optgroup` with class `a` that is an `option`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('select optgroup[label]["a"] option:eq(0),select:eq(1) option:eq(0)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

**Demo :** 
visit : http://jsfiddle.net/wBW4N/
and inspect selectboxes

Comment: that doesn't completely work, I think you meant `$('select optgroup[label="a"] option:eq(0),select:eq(1) option:eq(0)')`. also it needs to be more generic. there are 10 other selects on the page. I don't want to code for each one manually